# Recomendation regarding shopify theme developmnet

Tags: shopify

Well, Our company has bought shopify theme and was happily using it. now we like make changes to this theme, mostly cosmetic changes, like changing card colors add some background images, then some layout change.

My question is/are:

1) Can we use bootstrap with existing theme?
2) Does making change to css of existing theme get replace if there is theme update, like WordPress?
3) How can we set it up so we can develop new design locally but our store stays live with old design until we're done developing new one?

Comment: Kindly follow guide of the theme. If you use whole bootstrap with your current theme it will make theme slower. 

You can duplicate theme in shopify store easily and work in duplicate theme without making it live.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can we use bootstrap with existing theme?

- ANS: Yes you can use bootstrap in your theme. You just need to include the bootstrap in your new templates and you are ready to go.

2. Does making change to css of existing theme get replace if there is theme update, like WordPress?

- ANS: Suppose you'd added some CSS or custom code in your theme then new update will not replace your code. What will happen is you need to add the updates code manually in your theme. For reference you can read this article [Updating themes](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/os/using-themes/managing-themes/updating-themes).

3. How can we set it up so we can develop new design locally but our store stays live with old design until we're done developing new one?

- ANS: You can use [theme kit](https://shopify.github.io/themekit/) for local development. To stay live with old theme, you just need to make copy of the theme and used its ID in your theme kit.
  When you start learning theme Kit then you will know what is theme ID.

Hope this information will help you.
Best of luck.